# Application.Exit and cyclic references

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, winui-3, c++-winrt

`Application.Exit` wont close the process. The UI remains interactive.

Is this because I have cyclic references?

How do I find cyclic references without reasoning about the code?

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is not a problem statement. Everything following that is meaningless verbiage. See [ask] and fix the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cyclic references don't affect `Application.Exit`.

It turns out I was hitting the rough edges of the api by hacking `Xaml::Controls::Grid` with a combination reusing named xaml components with components created from code behind:

- `Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Append`
- `Grid.Children.Append`
- `Grid.SetColumnSpan`

I broke the first rule of programming: avoid the rough edges

Comment: You could accept your reply so it would help others who are facing the same issue.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT you have to wait 3 days before you can accept your own answer